# Safe project-agnostic way to specify JDK for Gradle?

Tags: gradle

As we know, it is possible to specify JDK path in `gradle.properties` at the project level, in property: `org.gradle.java.home`. However, this file may be under VCS (i.e. git). Users may have different paths for JDK, hence we can't commit this file.

Is there any safe, project-agnostic way to specify this property, so it works for users and different projects? Maybe using some environment property?

EDIT
I am looking a way to specify JDK *per project* but not be forced to commit this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wording is a little confusing since if you place the property in a non-VCS location (like an environment variable) it's not really "cross-user" since every user will have to configure this explicitly.

If you simply want to set properties in a way that is outside of version control there are several ways to do this.

- Use an environment variable, like you mention. Simply prefix it with `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_`. For example,  `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_javahome` would then be available in your build script as `javahome`.
- Place the properties in a file located at *USER_HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties*.
- Specify the property via the CLI with the `-P` option.
- Use something like the [Gradle properties plugin](https://github.com/stevesaliman/gradle-properties-plugin) to place additional properties in a separate file ignored by VCS.

Comment: I've updated my question. What am I looking for is way to specify JDK _per project_, but not to commit this path. It looks like your point #3 is the only way?

Comment: Or maybe we should not commit `gradle.properties`?

Comment: You could have your VCS ignore `gradle.properties` but that would preclude you for using it as a location for other properties in the future.

Comment: Yeah, exactly; thats why we have it already in git. I would not mind to have an alternative properties file (`gradle.<username>.properties`) for user-only settings.

Comment: The [Gradle properties plugin](https://github.com/stevesaliman/gradle-properties-plugin) might be a solution.

Comment: This looks like a solution! Can you add this to the answer, I will check it meanwhile, so I can mark the answer as corrected.

Comment: Unfortunately, Gradle properties plugin [does not work](https://github.com/stevesaliman/gradle-properties-plugin/issues/19) for setting JDK; still I marked your answer.